# Unable to consume with specific consumer group on a Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When I try to consume a topic with a specific consumer group it fails.
I can consume the same topic with a new consumer group.
When describe command is used on the topic there are no consumers attached to any partitions:

```
GROUP           TOPIC                   PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                  HOST            CLIENT-ID
dracg          clog                    1          105288          105588          300             -                                            -               -
dracg          clog                    2          104232          104532          300             -                                            -               -
dracg          clog                    3          104525          104820          295             -                                            -               -
dracg          clog                    0          104941          105243          302             -                                            -               -
```

Even console consumer code cannot consume with this consumer group
I'm giving relevant -group join- section of console consumer log below, group leader

```
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Joining group with current subscription: [clog] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending JoinGroup (JoinGroupRequestData(groupId='dracg', sessionTimeoutMs=10000, rebalanceTimeoutMs=300000, memberId='consumer-1-0d44d911-c975-4dfe-83d9-4b96b5fc9638', groupInstanceId='null', protocolType='consumer', protocols=[JoinGroupRequestProtocol(name='range', metadata=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 23, 112, 114, 101, 112, 114, 111, 100, 45, 70, 66, 77, 66, 45, 99, 104, 97, 110, 110, 101, 108, 108, 111, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0])])) to coordinator kafkanode3.example.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Received successful JoinGroup response: JoinGroupResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, generationId=5117, protocolName='range', leader='rdkafka-b5a0e7ac-8311-410f-bf04-b2b2712bad7a', memberId='consumer-1-0d44d911-c975-4dfe-83d9-4b96b5fc9638', members=[]) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending follower SyncGroup to coordinator kafkanode3.example.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null): SyncGroupRequestData(groupId='dracg', generationId=5117, memberId='consumer-1-0d44d911-c975-4dfe-83d9-4b96b5fc9638', groupInstanceId='null', assignments=[]) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Successfully joined group with generation 5117 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Enabling heartbeat thread (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Setting newly assigned partitions:  (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator kafkanode3.example.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Received successful Heartbeat response (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Completed asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator kafkanode3.example.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Received successful Heartbeat response (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator kafkanode3.example.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=dracg] Received successful Heartbeat response (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
```

Kafka version 2.3.0
If you have any clue on this please share.

Comment: Can you show which commands with console consumer are working and which ones are not working? At the moment it is not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @mike the only parameter that is different is consumer group.
failed one:
 --bootstrap-server $BS --consumer.config commands.config --group dracg --topic clog  --from-beginning
Working one:
 --bootstrap-server $BS --consumer.config commands.config --group atacg --topic clog  --from-beginning
Messages can be configured with any consumer group accept dracg